# Entity Framework builder try to generate the table twice

Tags: asp.net, database, .net-core, entity-framework-core

The following code always tries to generate the server database table twice.

User

```
public class User : IdentityUser {
  public ICollection<IdentityRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<UserServer> Servers { get; set; }
}
```

TestServer

```
public class TestServer {
  public string TestServerId { get; set; }

  // This throw the error
  [InverseProperty("User")]
  public string UserId { get; set; }
  public virtual User.User User { get; set; }
}
```

Program

```
// Entity Framework startup for generating the database tables.
....
// User
var userContext = services.GetRequiredService<UserContext>();
userContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
UserContextInitializer.Initialize(userContext);

// Server
var serverContext = services.GetRequiredService<ServerContext>();
serverContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
ServerContextInitializer.Initialize(serverContext);

// TestServer
// Error throw here: Table 'Server' already exists ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'Server' already exists

var testServerContxt = services.GetRequiredService<TestServerContext>();
var creator2 = (RelationalDatabaseCreator) testServerContxt.Database.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>();
creator2.CreateTables();
testServerContxt.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Why is Entity Framework attempting to generate the `Server` table and not `TestServer` table?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Timo

Comment: Is the "Server" table associated with the `UserServer` entity? If yes, it is included via `TestServer.User` -> `User.Servers`. See [Including & Excluding Types - Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-types#conventions).

Comment: @IvanStoev With the Including and Excluding the error is aways. Problem is the UserId is not linked with the UserId in the User table. How I can solve this?

Comment: Ignore `UserServer` and remove `[InverseProperty("User")]`. But sharing an entity between is not a good idea IMHO. 1 database == 1 db context.